# Linked List overload addition

Tags: c++, linked-list, operator-overloading

I am trying to overload addition using Linked lists and have hit a wall. I am adding 2 linked lists together and each node is added individually but if I add two lists which contain 999 and 999 then it shows 181818 instead of the correct answer and I am kinda lost. It seems to work sometimes though like if I use 500 and 500.

```
LinkedList LinkedList::operator+( LinkedList &obj)
{
    LinkedList sum;
    ListNode *nodePtr;
    ListNode *nodePtr2;

    nodePtr = head;
    nodePtr2 = obj.head;

    while (nodePtr && nodePtr2)
    {
        sum.appendNode(nodePtr->value + nodePtr2->value);//append node adds a new node containing the value at the end of the list.
        nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
        nodePtr2 = nodePtr2->next;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: How is the number 999 kept in your linked list? Is it kept as an integer 999 in a single node? Or is it kept as three nodes having the digit 9 in each of them?

Comment: Each number is entered into a node individually. so 3 nodes for 999.

Answer (score 0):

From your code and your post, it appears that each linked list is a list of the digits of a number. You are trying to add two numbers by adding the matching list items of two linked lists. But this will fail pretty fast in at least 2 cases:

1. The two elements you add return a sum greater than 10 and they are in the middle of the number. In this case, you need to "carry the one", as we learned in 2nd grade. This will involve some more list work that you don't have here.
2. If the two numbers are of different length. The while loop will simply ignore the extra digits of the longer number.

And yes it works for 500 + 500 -- that doesn't violate either of the 2 cases I mentioned above.

So, I'd change your `while` loop to something like this:

```
int carryVal = 0;
while (...) {
    ...
    int sum = nodePtr->value + nodePtr2->value;
    int thisDigitVal = sum % 10 + carryVal; // First digit of the sum, plus any carry from previous digit
    sum.appendNode(thisDigitVal);
    carryVal = sum / 10; // carry for next digit (division by int will truncate -- thats what we want)
    ...
}
```

Couple of notes:

1. You will probably have to change your `while` condition to work with numbers of different lengths and also to deal with any final carry.
2. This will only work with summing 2 numbers. For 3 or more, you will have to deal with the case where `int thisDigitVal = sum % 10 + carryVal;` returns a value > 9 and thus add another 1 to the carry for the next digit.

Comment: Thanks, how would I go about fixing the first problem? I know how to "carry the one" but I am having trouble trying to implement that in the program.

Comment: @Native I added some ideas for you to the answer.